# Get starting 10 characters from matched string in a field using logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want to get the first 10 characters from a string that ends with Exception. 
Example: I have field like this:

```
 "ERRORMESSAGE" => "local exporter [default_local] - failed to delete indice
s\r\nRemoteTransportException[[data-2][10.0.x.x:x300][indices:admin/delete]];
 nested: IndexNotFoundException[no such index];\r\nCaused by: [.marvel-es-1-2017
.06.07] IndexNotFoundException[no such index]\r\n        at org.elasticsearch.cl
uster.metadata.MetaDataDeleteIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataDeleteIndexService.j
ava:91)\r\n        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateUpdateTask.execute(C
lusterStateUpdateTask.java:45)\r\n        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.I
nternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:468)\r\n
  at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run
(InternalClusterService.java:772)\r\n        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.co
ncurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndCl
ean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)\r\n        at org.elasticsearch.co
mmon.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunna
ble.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)\r\n        at java.util.concur
rent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\r\n        at ja
va.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\r\
n        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r",
```

Where i need to catch the string that ends with Exception. For that i had used this

```
grok {
  match => ["ERRORMESSAGE", "(?<ExceptionType>{10}.Exception)"]
}
```

Where i am finding the first 10 characters of a string that ends with Exception but i am getting this error `{:exception=>"RegexpError"` . And also other problem is if there are more strings that ends with Exception in `ERRORTYPE` field then whether above grok produces two or more `ExceptionType` fields ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct regex is `(?<ExceptionType>.{10}Exception)`. The quantifier (`{10}`) has to be before the token it quantify (`.`) (at least it's how I understand it, I'm not a regex expert).

The grok filter will return with the first match.
In your example, it will be `eTransportException`.

Comment: Also, to test your grok patterns, you can use http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

Comment: Is it possible to get the second one exnotfoundException by giving exceptiontype[1] like this? Because it is showing the first matched one

Comment: @C.Yaswanth You could add a second element Exception (like this: `(?<ExceptionType>.{10}Exception).*(?<ExceptionType2>.{10}Exception)`) in your pattern, but it would break the grok filter if there is only one Exception in the trace.